# Angular ui.grid getting filtered dataset

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I m actually trying to developp a little application using de ui.grid library and I m facing problems when getting the data result set on a filter.

In fact, everything works great, I can filter, I can make opération on each line, but I cant get the full result set of a filter using :

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering

Can you help ?

I repeat : everything works great, I can sort and filter, but I cant get my resultset

Thanks for advance & have a nice day ! :D

Comment: An example, like a plnkr would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "get my resultset"?

I'm assuming this means you want to programmatically get at the filtered list of rows.  ui-grid doesn't provide an API for doing that, but you can get it from `gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache`.  This will give you a list of the current visible rows.

You can extract the original entities from your data array from those rows, the entity is typically in `row.entity`.